# Number on the back of the football shirt

Tags: phrase-request

I want to ask someone who plays football what number stands on the back of his football shirt... What's the correct way to put it?

Comment: What about player number or player's number?

Comment: Thank you, guys! So I asked & it was exactly the number I wanted to hear : ) thank y'all (sorry, cannot upvote...)

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about American football, I would say "What's your jersey number?" or "Oh you play football? What's your number?". I'd probably use the same terms for most sports, although I'm not a sports fan and I'm not sure that "jersey" is the best choice for all team sports.

Some [other suggestions from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_(sports)) are

- uniform number
- squad number
- jersey number
- shirt number
- sweater number

Answer (score 2):

I would personally just ask them directly:

> What number are you?

This, of course, has to be in context - you must already be talking about them playing football.